# tumblr masonry + infinite scrolling overlapping posts despite using desandro and new jquery

Tags: jquery, tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am new to javascript and stuff and now I have a frustrating issue with masonry and infinite scroll on tumblr.
I have read nearly all the forum questions about those issues but nothing solved my problem.

So, I have a tumblr blog (http://jessman5.tumblr.com) and despite of using:

- //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
- http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js
- http://masonry.desandro.com/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js

and this code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
var container = $('#container');

    container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : '.pagination',    
            nextSelector : '.pagination a',
            itemSelector : '.post',
            loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
              img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
        },
        function( newElements ) {
            var newElems = $( newElements );
            newElems.css({ opacity: 0 });
            newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            container.masonry( 'appended', newElems); 
        }
    );
    container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post'
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

the posts are overlapping when it comes to load older posts. 
Safari is doing it well for a while but Chrome and Firefox are completely lost.

I tried to include this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options...
  });
});
```

and this:

```
container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        container.masonry({
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                return containerWidth / 100;
            }
        });
    });
```

and (feels like) hundreds of other versions of code... 
nothing of this is working for me.

I hope anyone can help me.
I'm frustrated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKay here is the code which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var container = $('#container');

container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post'
    });
});

container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.pagination',    
      nextSelector : '.pagination a',
      itemSelector : '.post',
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

I just had to flip it, right? haha :D

Answer (score 3):

When trying to debug code, *always* check the console for errors. The console states this:

```
cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'appended'
```

I can see that you're trying to initialise masonry on the `window.load` method, however your infinitescroll code is firing on document ready, which fires *before* `window.load`. That's why the error still occurs.

Try initialising both infinitescroll and masonry in the `document.ready` method, or both in the `window.load` method, and you should get it to work. Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').masonry({
        // options
    });

    $('#container').infinitescroll({
        // etc
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! :) I solved my Issue.
I will post the final code when I'm able to answer to my own question later.

Comment: 2 things to note - answers on stack overflow are there to help _other people_ as well as you. So you don't need to unaccept answers and post your working code, because that's irrelevant to other people who have the same problem with different code. What they need to know the _actual problem_ and _how to solve it_ which is what my answer explains. Also, be aware that unaccepting answers penalises the answerer (aka me), so if you intend to answer your own question, please don't accept/unnaccept other answers :)