# Infinite AJAX Scroll with Masonry and PHP image gallery Images Overlapping

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, infinite

ok, first time question. I have a php script that pulls images from a folder into list items and it has pagination options as well. I applied Masonry to make the grid and now I'm trying (quite unsucessfully) to integrate [ajax infinite scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/support.html) so i can pull the new images incrementally, as the final gallery will be quite large.
So far the infinite scroll is loading sequential pages underneath and stacking the additional pages. If i take masonry off, it seems to work as expected.

**source code:**

```
        ...
        #masonry ul {
            width:100%;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #masonry li {
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #imageList {border:2px solid;}
            .ias-trigger {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px; 
            left:300px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="masonry">
        <ul id="imageList">
            <?php
                $dsg_pagination_per_page = 10;
                $dsg_thumb_operation = 'scale';
                $dsg_thumb_width = 300;
                $dsg_thumb_height =300;
            ?>
            <?php include 'dsg.php'; ?>
        </ul>
     </div>  
    <br>
    <?php echo $dsg_pagination_nav; // print pagination links ?>
    <script>
        var $container = $('#imageList');
        //initialize Masonry after all images have loaded  
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry();
        });

        var ias = $.ias({
            container: "#imageList",
            item: ".item",
            delay:1200,
            pagination: "#pagination",
            next: ".next a"
        });
        ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
        ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div style="text-align:center; position:absolute; bottom:0; left0;"><p><em>You reached the end!</em></p></div>'}));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**rendered code:**
http://m-casper.com/sample/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

found my answer from another post after a week of searching:

[tumblr masonry + infinite scrolling overlapping posts despite using desandro and new jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460370/tumblr-masonry-infinite-scrolling-overlapping-posts-despite-using-desandro-and?rq=1)